# Java Calendar/Date issue

Tags: java

I'm building a list of Months I'm using as headers for a table in a JSP.

What I’m doing is comparing what the month is I'm getting from the database and iterating or "trying" to all the way up to that month.  In the case, the Month is November

The problem is I'm only able to build a list from October 2012 to October 2013

My logic looks sound, I'm not sure what else I can try.

Starting point and compare..From the database the key is

```
int effortYear = 2013
Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
         max.set(effortYear,8,1,0,0,0);
   for (ItemUnitBean item:  scheduledBeans)

       {
             ItemUnitBean bean = new ItemUnitBean();
          for(Entry<Date, ItemPhasing> en : item.getScheduledItemByMonth().entrySet() )
           {
System.out.println( "KEY= " + en.getKey() );  // KEY =2013-11-01 
  if ( en.getKey().compareTo(max.getTime()) > 0 ) 
              {
                    max.setTime(en.getKey());
              }

           }
          finalScheduledBeans.add(bean);
       }
```

Now Building the list:

```
TreeSet<Date> scheduledMonthList = new TreeSet<Date>();
  Calendar temp = Calendar.getInstance();
         temp.set(effortYear-1,9,1,0,0,0);

         do 
         {
             scheduledMonthList.add(temp.getTime());
             System.out.println("montList= " + temp.getTime()  );
             temp.add( Calendar.MONTH, 1 );


         }  while( temp.compareTo(max) <= 0 );
```

This is what the logger spits out:

[image]

Can anyone see why Nov is not being added to the list??

Comment: *"`en.getKey() );  // KEY =2013-11-01`"* => are you sure?

Comment: if i do a print of max when the loop is done it says `gregorianCalendar[timme=1383278400000,month=10]`

Comment: I think it might be the do while loop thats causing the issue.....

Comment: I would suggest you write a simple example where you set the max variable manually and see what happens.

Comment: This may shed some light on whats happening http://ideone.com/uPEGny. And here the milliseconds http://ideone.com/ymYGl3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting your loop with a calendar set to now, and where you reset the year, month, date, hour, minute and second. But you don't set the milliseconds to 0.

So once you reach October, you add one month, and obtain November *+ some milliseconds*. And November *+ some millisesonds* is bigger than November *+ 0 millisecond*.

Comment: Where does he set the calendar to now?

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance()` returns a calendar set to now.

Comment: You are right, the problem he sets the values but there is no way to set milliseconds for Calendar. Thats why the differ slightly. http://ideone.com/ymYGl3

Comment: Of course there is a way: `calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);`

Comment: whoa....that was like looking for a needle in a needle.....im about to try adding `max.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);`...and `temp.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);`

Comment: @JBNizet you are right(again) ;) I only looked at the set methods to set multiple fields.

Comment: Well done - I'm still stunned by this example: http://ideone.com/hLWrRG - the output is different when you comment out the first println....

Comment: @Stefan: That's understandable. I've always wondered wht they chose to provide a method setting all the fields... except one. Now if it was the only problem with the Calendar and Date classes...

Comment: @assylias Its probably because the invocation is faster than 1 millisecond, so both Calendar instances have the same millisecond part if you leave out the debug statement.